# How can I retrieve the EDIT mode rotation of a curve?

Tags: bevel

How can I retrieve the rotation of a curve in EDIT mode?

I rotated a Bevel-object curve in edit mode.
How can I now retrieve the actual current edit-mode-rotation of the curve?